# get all data for a specific user in solidity

Tags: solidity

how can  i get all the associated data with a specific a customer by providing customer id and is it smarter to save any the basic data such as ids, names, etc in blockchain or IPFS ?

```
struct {

  uint256 customer_Id;
  bytes32 customerName;
  bytes32 customerAddress;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing DAPP for public permissionless blockchain network
then I will recommend use IPFS for storing user data. Storing data on the blockchain has its own cost(gas) associated with it. Saving data on IPFS provides a unique hash. Instead of storing the data on the contract, one can store the hash on the contract and then one can use the hash to retrieve the data.

You can use [IPFS-Store](https://github.com/ConsenSys/IPFS-Store) which provides search and querying capabilities on top of IPFS.